# Calculate the next date, with the start date and the working days

Tags: javascript

I want to share a code to ask for support to check if it can be improved.

I use this Easter formula: [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Implementaciones_del_algoritmo_de_c%C3%A1lculo_de_la_fecha_de_Pascua), and the next constants:

```
const MIN_EN_SEGUNDOS = 60000   ; /* 60*1000                --> SEG*MILSEG */
const HRS_EN_SEGUNDOS = 3600000 ; /* 60*MIN_EN_SEGUNDOS     --> MIN*SEG*MILSEG */
const DIA_EN_SEGUNDOS = 86400000; /* 24*HRS_EN_SEGUNDOS     --> HRS*MIN*SEG*MILSEG */
```

This is my code, which calculates the holidays according to the year to be calculated, as well as taking into account bank holidays in Mexico

```
function doBusinessNatural(start_day, business_days){
  var days_business=0, evalua_anio=0, i, start_day_valid ='';
  var arrHolidays =[];
  start_day = new Date(start_day);
  var start_day_valid = (start_day instanceof Date && !isNaN(start_day.valueOf()));
  if(!start_day_valid) start_day = new Date();
  i         = start_day;
  var evalua_mes=-1, ini_day=0, last_day=0, natural_days=0, number_of_days=0, bus_day=0, bus_day_check=0;
  
  function Holidays(Anio){
    var DomingoPascua,JuevesSanto,ViernesSanto;
    
    if(Anio!=evalua_anio){
      function getHoliday(Anio, Mes, sec){
        var evalua_dia;
        evalua_dia    = (new Date(Anio,Mes,1)).getDay();
        evalua_dia    = ((evalua_dia==0)? 2:(evalua_dia>1)? (9-evalua_dia):1)+sec;
        evalua_dia    = (new Date(Anio,Mes,evalua_dia));
        return evalua_dia;
      }
      
      arrHolidays   = [];
      
      DomingoPascua = pascua(Anio);
      JuevesSanto   = new Date(DomingoPascua.getFullYear(),DomingoPascua.getMonth(),DomingoPascua.getDate()-3);
      ViernesSanto  = new Date(DomingoPascua.getFullYear(),DomingoPascua.getMonth(),DomingoPascua.getDate()-2);
      /* Semana santa */
      arrHolidays.push(DomingoPascua)
      arrHolidays.push(JuevesSanto)
      arrHolidays.push(ViernesSanto)
      /* Dias que se mueven a otro día por ley */
      /* 5/Febrero ->  primer lunes de Febrero / Día de la Constitución Mexicana */
      arrHolidays.push(getHoliday(Anio,1,0));
      /* 21/Marzo ->  tercer lunes / Natalicio de Benito Juárez */
      arrHolidays.push(getHoliday(Anio,2,14));
      /* 20/Nov ->  tercer lunes / Revolución Mexicana*/
      arrHolidays.push(getHoliday(Anio,10,14));
      /* Dias feriados fijos */
      arrHolidays.push(new Date(Anio,0,1));    /* 01/Ene      - Año Nuevo  */
      arrHolidays.push(new Date(Anio,4,1));    /* 01/may      - Dia del trabajo */
      arrHolidays.push(new Date(Anio,8,16));   /* 16/Sep      - Día de la Independencia */
      arrHolidays.push(new Date(Anio,10,2));   /* 02/Nov      - Dia de muertos */
      arrHolidays.push(new Date(Anio,11,12));  /* 12/Dic      - V Guadalupe / Día del empleado bancario */
      arrHolidays.push(new Date(Anio,11,24));  /* 25/Dic      - Navidad */
      
      evalua_anio= Anio;
    }
  }
  function verificaHDays(Mes, Dia, typo){
    bus_day_check = 0;
    for(var x=0; x<arrHolidays.length;x++){
      if((arrHolidays[x]).getMonth()==Mes){
        var l_v = (arrHolidays[x]).getDay();
        if(typo==0){
          if(((l_v!=0)&&(l_v!=6))&&(arrHolidays[x]).getDate()>Dia) bus_day_check ++
        }else{
          if(((l_v!=0)&&(l_v!=6))&&(arrHolidays[x]).getDate()==Dia) bus_day_check ++
        }        
      }
    }
    return bus_day_check;
  }
  
  var Anio, Mes, Dia;
  while(days_business<business_days){
    Anio = i.getFullYear(); Mes = i.getMonth(); Dia = i.getDate();
    Holidays(Anio,evalua_anio);
    
    if(Mes!=evalua_mes){
      last_day     = (new Date(Anio,Mes+1,0));                     /* calcula cuando es el último día del mes */
      ini_day      = i;
      natural_days = (Math.trunc((last_day - ini_day)/DIA_EN_SEGUNDOS)); /* Diferencia de días */
      bus_day      = natural_days - Math.trunc((i.getDay()+natural_days)/7)*2;       /* calcula los días hábiles - festivos */
      /* dias festivos del mes */
      bus_day_check = verificaHDays(Mes, Dia, 0);
      bus_day -= bus_day_check
      /* cubre el mes ?? */
      if((days_business+bus_day)<business_days){
        number_of_days += natural_days;
        days_business  += bus_day;
      } else {
        while(ini_day<last_day){
          i = new Date(Anio,Mes,Dia);              /* actualiza el día a evaluar */
          ini_day = i;                             /* actualiza ini_day*/
          bus_day_check  = verificaHDays(Mes, Dia, 1);
          days_business += bus_day_check + ((i.getDay()==0)||(i.getDay()==6))? 0:1;
          number_of_days ++;
          /* Verifica si llegó al final */
          if((business_days-days_business)==0) break;
          Dia ++;
        }
      }
      /* brinco mes y busco el primer día del siguiente mes / ¿Qué pasa con el resto? */
      i= new Date(Anio,Mes+1,1);  /* cambia de mes */
    }
  }
  // Anio = start_day.getFullYear(); Mes = start_day.getMonth(); Dia = start_day.getDate();
  // ini_day = Math.trunc(((new Date(Anio,Mes,Dia,0,0,0)).getTime())/DIA_EN_SEGUNDOS)+number_of_days
  // ini_day = new Date(ini_day*DIA_EN_SEGUNDOS)
  // return ini_day;

  return number_of_days;
}
```

My code works fine in most cases, but at month changes, sometimes it's not so efficient.

Comment: Questions are supposed to be asked in English here. Please do not try to make them "bilingual" by adding each sentence in two different languages, that is only confusing to the majority of readers here.

Comment: [Can I ask a question in a language other than English?](/help/non-english-questions) Summary: no. If you feel more comfortable asking in Spanish, feel free to visit our sister site [es.so]. Also, [codereview.se] is dedicated to code reviews like this and might be a better fit for your question. Be sure to read their FAQ (English only for instance!) before posting there though.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.